# Filter/Query Wildcard Issue - AWS OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, lucene

I'm looking into OpenSearch and trying out the dashboards & data querying but am having some difficulty with some specific queries I'd like to run.

The data I have streaming into OpenSearch is a set of custom error logs which the @message field contains json such as: `...{"code":400,"message":"Bad request","detail":"xxxx"}...` (the entire message field is not valid json as it contains other data too)

I can specifically query for the code field with `"code:400"` but would like a more generic query to match all 4XX codes but adding any type of wildcard or range breaks the query and the quotes surrounding it are required otherwise the results include `code OR 400`

Is there any way to achieve this with the kind of data I have or is this a limitation in the querying syntax?

Comment: I had the same problem and atm it is not possible to preserve the order given by the string "code 400" using code AND 400. Maybe you could try to use a different tokenizer (the standard one strips the special characters like : or ") or try to extract and parse the JSONs you need.

Comment: Thanks @dcolazin, I did see something about the tokenizer but couldn't see how to change it or any way to extract subsets of data from a field, any advice?

Comment: Maybe tokenize the whole JSON fields as "fieldname":fieldvalue as by default you will get the tokens ("code","400","message","bad","request",...) but you you have a token like "\"code\":400"...